# Unexpected results while bit-shifting in C

Tags: c

I just hit some unexpected behavior while porting some code. I've boiled it down to this example:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

uint32_t swap_16_p(uint8_t *value)
{
    return (*(uint16_t*)value << 8 | *(uint16_t*)value >> 8);
}

int main()
{
    uint8_t start[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xBE, 0xEF };
    printf("0x%08x\n", swap_16_p(start));
    return 0;
}
```

On a Little Endian system like x86-64 I would expect this to print `0x0000dead` but instead it prints `0x00addead`. Looking at the assembly output makes the issue more clear:

```
uint32_t swap_16_p(uint8_t *value)
{
  400506:       55                      push   %rbp
  400507:       48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  40050a:       48 89 7d f8             mov    %rdi,-0x8(%rbp)
    return (*(uint16_t*)value << 8 | *(uint16_t*)value >> 8);
  40050e:       48 8b 45 f8             mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rax
  400512:       0f b7 00                movzwl (%rax),%eax
  400515:       0f b7 c0                movzwl %ax,%eax
  400518:       c1 e0 08                shl    $0x8,%eax
  40051b:       89 c2                   mov    %eax,%edx
  40051d:       48 8b 45 f8             mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rax
  400521:       0f b7 00                movzwl (%rax),%eax
  400524:       66 c1 e8 08             shr    $0x8,%ax
  400528:       0f b7 c0                movzwl %ax,%eax
  40052b:       09 d0                   or     %edx,%eax
}
  40052d:       5d                      pop    %rbp
  40052e:       c3                      retq
```

By using eax as the scratch area for doing the computation, the extra byte gets shifted past the 16-bit boundary with `shl $0x8,%eax`. I wouldn't have expected the computation to be treated as a 32-bit value until just before the return (as it would need to promote it to a uint32_t); similar behavior is seen when storing the value in a temporary uint32_t and the printing that instead.

Have I gone against (or improperly interpreted) the C spec, or is this a compiler bug (seems unlikely since this happens in both clang and GCC)?

Comment: Probably integer promotion.

Comment: On a RISC machine, you could easily induce bus errors (SIGBUS signals, leading to a core dump) when you try to treat a pointer to an 8-bit quantity as a 16-bit quantity.  You are treading on thin ice there.

Comment: If you expect `0x0000dead` as the result you can use `uint16_t a = *(uint16_t *)value << 8; uint16_t b = *(uint16_t *)value >> 8; return a | b;`

Comment: Or, if you want a 16-bit value returned, say that the function returns a 16-bit value: `uint16_t swap_16_p(…)`.

Comment: do your maths: `0xadde << 8 | 0xadde >> 8` *is* `0xaddead`

Comment: @hroptatyr It's not a matter of understanding bitshifting; OP probably didn't understand integer promotion rules in C. `0xadde << 8` *is* `0xde00` if everything is in `uint16_t`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integer promotions are done at the "read side", therefore while the expression is evaluated. This means that after reading an integer value that has a smaller size than `int` resp. `unsigned` it is immediately converted:

> The following may be used in an expression wherever an int or unsigned int may be used:
>
> ￼— An object or expression with an integer type whose integer conversion rank is less than or equal to the rank of int and unsigned int.
>
> — A bit-field of type _Bool, int, signed int, or unsigned int.
>
> If an int can represent all values of the original type, the value is converted to an int; otherwise, it is converted to an unsigned int. These are called the integer promotions. 48)
>
> 48) The integer promotions are applied only: as part of the usual arithmetic conversions, to certain argument expressions, to the operands of the unary +, -, and ~ operators, and to both operands of the shift operators, as specified by their respective subclauses.

ISO/IEC 9899:TC3 6.3.1.1-2

Therefore

```
*(uint16_t*)value
```

is immediately converted to `int` and then shifted.

Answer (score 2):

On a little endian system you are reading a `unit16_t` memory location that contains value `0xADDE`. Before performing shifts, the value is promoted to `int` type, which is probably 32-bit wide on your platform, producing `0x0000ADDE`. Shifts produce `0x00ADDE00` and `0x000000AD` respectively. Bitwise OR produces `0x00ADDEAD`.

Everything is as expected.

C language does not perform any arithmetic operations within types smaller than `int` (or `unsigned int`). Any smaller type is always promoted to `int` (or `unsigned int`) before performing the operation. This is what happens with your shifts. Your shifts are `int` shifts. C does not have "narrower" shifts. C does not have "narrower" additions and multiplications. C does not have "narrower" *anything*.

If you want a "narrower" shift (or any other operation) you have to simulate it by meticulously manually truncating the intermediate results in order to force them into a smaller type

```
(uint16_t) (*(uint16_t*) value << 8) | (uint16_t) (*(uint16_t*) value >> 8);
```

They will constantly spring back to `int` and you have to constantly beat them back into `uint16_t`.

Answer (score 1):

This is what the compiler does:

```
uint32_t swap_16_p(uint8_t *value)
{
    uint16_t v1 = *(uint16_t*)value;  // -> 0x0000ADDE
    int v2 = v1 << 8;                 // -> 0x00ADDE00
    int v3 = v1 >> 8;                 // -> 0x000000AD
    uint32_t v4 = v2 | v3;            // -> 0x00ADDEAD
    return v4;
}
```

So the result is well-justified.

Please note that `v2` and `v3` are results of *integral promotion*.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at your logic:

```
return (*(uint16_t*)value << 8 | *(uint16_t*)value >> 8);
```

`*(uint16_t*)value` is `0xADDE` since your system is little-endian.  (Subject to some caveats which I will mention below).

`0xADDE << 8` is `0xADDE00`, assuming you have 32-bit (or larger) `int`. Remember that left-shifting is equivalent to multiplying by a power of 2.

`0xADDE >> 8` is `0xAD`.

`0xADDE00 | 0xAD` is `0xADDEAD` which is what you observed.

If you expected to `0xDEAD` then you are going about it completely the wrong way. Instead the following code would work (and be endian-agnostic):

```
return (value[0] << 8) | value[1];
```

although my personal preference, since we are doing arithmetic, is to write it as `value[0] * 0x100u + value[1]`.

---

`*(uint16_t *)value` has other problems. Firstly it will cause undefined behaviour if your system has an alignment restriction on integers. Secondly, it violates the strict aliasing rule: objects of type `uint8_t` may not be read through an lvalue of type `uint16_t`, again causing undefined behaviour.

If you are porting code that uses aliasing casts like this, I'd suggest disabling type-based aliasing optimization in your compiler until you fully understand the issues. In gcc the flag is `-fno-strict-aliasing`.